# ArcGIS JavaScript Sketch defaultCreateOptions

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I want to change the `defaultCreateOptions` `mode` to `"click"` only. I want to disable adding of point when pointer is dragged. I am trying the following code but it doesn't work.

```
var sketch = new Sketch({    
 view: view,    
 layer: graphicsLayer,    
 defaultCreateOptions: {    
  mode: "click"    
 }    
});
```

Adding `defaultCreateOptions` has no effect. It is still using its default options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. As per the ArcGIS documentation, **defaultCreateOptions** was introduced since **version 4.14** and my javascript reference was set to 4.13. I changed it to 4.14 and it solved my problem.